# How to do in-memory and on disk data caching in watchkit extension?

Tags: ios, caching, watchkit

I have an ios app which sends data in key value pairs to watchkit extension, so now I want to cache that key value pairs both in memory and on disk at watchkit extension. So what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is there other way rather than NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using key/value pairs, it seems straightforward to keep your data in a `NSDictionary` while in-memory. To persist the dictionary to disk:

```
[myDictionary writeToFile:@"MyFile" atomically:YES];
```

To load the dictionary back from disk:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary =
  [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"MyFile"];
```

For what it's worth, `NSArray` supports the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Is there another way to do this without using files? I mean does apple provide any api for accomplishing this task on watchkit extension?

Comment: There is no API to do what you're asking (short of the already-mentioned `NSUserDefaults`). You could look at `NSCache`, but that doesn't persist to disk, so you'd have to implement that yourself.